# Forward Apache authentication to remote "Resource"

Tags: authentication

I want to implement some kind of "forwarding" apache authentication to a remote ressource.

Imagine multiple servers to be able to authenticate the same users.

Yes, I could do this via "AuthBasicProvider dbd", BUT: Every server must have database access. And this is possible a security problem.

I imagine some kind of authentication service where the Apache just forwards user and pass entered and get's back some "OK" oder "NOT OK" and does handle this as yes or no.

Is there anything like this in default Apache 2.4?

Comment: Technically, you could run an LDAP server, which does exactly that, but that might be a bit of overkill.

Comment: Also, you could roll your own with [mod_authnz_fcgi](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_fcgi.html), I guess.